# How to delete cookies in a web browser control in windows phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

In my app i'm using Web Browser Control. And in that i'm loading a web page, which contains **Cookies**. The reqiurement is that i should get all the cookies and then delete it from the web page.

My code,

```
cookies = browserControl.GetCookies();
if (cookies.Count == 0)
   {
   setURL();
   }
else
   {
    foreach (Cookie cookie in cookies)
        {
         bool check;
         // Store the value
         cookie.Discard = true;
         cookie.Expired = true;
         }
    }
 ClearCookie();
```

And the ClearCookie function is,

```
private async void ClearCookie()
    {
        await this.browserControl.ClearCookiesAsync();
    }
```

But the problem is that cookies are not deleted, How can i delete the cookies in the web page loaded in Web Browser Control(browsercontrol).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowserextensions(v=vs.105).aspx ClearCookieAsync();

Comment: how you verified that cookies weren't deleted?

Comment: Yes! Even after ClearCookie() function is called when i get cookies from browsercontrol, i get 7 cookies!

Answer (score 0):

If your app targets Windows Phone 8, there is a new simple API for clearing cookies: [ClearCookiesAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj571211%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

The instance of WebBrowser it's called on doesn't matter.
Sample code:

```
await new WebBrowser().ClearCookiesAsync();
```

Here is a tutorial that makes use of it: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Integrate_Facebook_to_Your_Windows_Phone_Application

Comment: You just need to to execute this line of code to delete cookies. What problem are you having?

Comment: Only the app's cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ClearCookiesAsync` function is very much straightforward, what else not clear?

```
await browserControl.ClearCookiesAsync();
```

that's the code that works to clear web browser control's cookies in your question context.

**UPDATE :**

Using `await` or not is a design decision according to your needs. If next codes need to be executed only after `ClearCookiesAsync` completed, then you need to add `await` keyword. And to be able to use `await` the function where it resides should be declared as `async`, as for example :

```
private async void MyFunction()
```

Otherwise, you can just remove `await` keyword, and keep your function declaration as is. Check [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) or search to know more about await/async feature in new .NET framework.

Comment: when i use the above mentioned code I get an error stating that, __The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.__

Comment: see my update, you have two options : just remove `await` keyword, or add `async` keyword to your method/function.

Comment: It is still not working! I've updated the code do have a look at it!